# Make EasyGridCombo REQUIRED in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having trouble making a `select` required in ExtJS.

I tried with `allowBlank: false`, even afterredner methods but nothing works, I can submit the form with no value in that select.

The code to generate the field is as follows:

```
OldType: function () {
        return {
            xtype: 'xEasyGridCombo',
            allowBlank: false,
            required: true,
            valueField: 'fe_code',
            displayField: 'fe_name',
            dropPanelConfig: {
                width: 480,
                height: 200
            },
            searchFieldList: ['fe_code', 'fe_name'],
            gridConfig: {
                table: 'type_store',
                idColumn: 'fe_id',
                hasBottomBar: true,
                rowLimit: 40,
                tools: [],
                conditions: [],
                forceColumns: ['fe_code', 'fe_name'],
                forceSelectFieldsQuery: ' DISTINCT fe_code, CONCAT(fe_name, \'[\', fe_code, \']\') fe_name ',
                xColumns: [],
                storeBaseParams: {}
            },
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function () {

                    let oGrid,
                        sDivision = this.findParentByType('panel').find('KeyNr1', 'Divsion')[0].getValue();
                    // making sure the grid is rendered
                    this.getGridList();
                    oGrid = this.gridList.findByType('uxgrid')[0];

                    oGrid.store.baseParams.filter = Ext.util.JSON.encode([{
                        "field": "fe_tip",
                        "value": (sDivision === '02') ? 'F-GAZ' : 'F-ELEC'
                    }]);
//store from server try
                    oGrid.store.reload();
                }
            }
        };
    },
```

What am I doing wrong ? I can't even make it have a default value.

Thanks in advance and happy Holidays !

Comment: May you provide some fiddle.sencha.com sample to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the modern toolkit, the formpanel has a beforesubmit event.  you can check if the value is selected or not.  If you return a false from this event the form will not be submitted.

in the classic toolkit the event is beforeaction.